# Node script that reads and writes file (readFileSync and writeFileSync) reads the file different on second run

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a node script that automates package updates within a package.json by reading the file, selecting the line with the package and giving the version a bump, and writing the new version of the file.

It runs fine when I run the script the first time. On the second run, readFileSync() gives a very different output, making the script break.

Here is the readFileSync function.

```
const data = fs.readFileSync("./package.json", {
  encoding: "utf8",
});
```

On the first run, data logs like this:

```
PS C:\Projects\update-version-test> node updateversion.js
Updating package: webpack , version: patch
data {
  "name": "update-version-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "eendkonijn",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

The script works as expected, and the webpack package is bumped to 5.8.1. If I run the script again, however, the data logs like this:

```
PS C:\Projects\update-version-test> node updateversion.js
Updating package: webpack , version: patch
} } "webpack": "^5.8.1"",-test",
```

The package.json file is intact but somehow readFileSync() doesn't seem to pick it up correctly the second run?

When I make a manual change, the script seems to be working again. But only the one time.

I have a reproduction here:

https://github.com/eendkonijn/update-version-test

Comment: there's a npm command that does this for you: npm version (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to parse the json file using `.split("\n")` and later you assemble the resulting json content using `.join("")`. In the resulting file there will be no more line-breaks which is why your code does not work the second time.

Instead of manually parsing the json content, just parse it using `JSON.parse`, manipulate the webpack-property and finally overwrite the file content with the output of `JSON.stringify`. E.g:

```
const rawData = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', {
    encoding: 'utf8',
});

const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
parsedData.dependencies.webpack = 'callFunctionToManipulateTheVersionHere()';

fs.writeFileSync('./package.json', JSON.stringify(parsedData, null, 4));
```

Comment: Ah I see, this is the way of doing it. Thank you, very helpful.